# when I search `localhost:3000/users`, it's said not found. What's wrong?

Tags: node.js, express

[image]
[image]

I'm using Express framework, `app.use()` in app.js and `router.get()` in users.js. When I search `localhost:3000/users/u` it works fine, but when I search `localhost:3000/users`, it's a 404 error. What's wrong?

Comment: Please don't include code as images but as (correctly formatted) text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `/users` call redirects to your `users.js` module and you don't handle `/` in it. To fix this, simply add the route:

```
// users.js

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('It works');
  // ...
});
```

Comment: But why the users function in app.use() can't handle when I call locahost:3000/users, there is also a fn in app.use called users?

Comment: Because you pass an "express.Router" (your `users` module) as second argument of the `app.use`. So, you have to write the `/` route in this router to catch the call.

Answer (score 0):

when call app.use('users',users), the users will be called and after that it will call router.handle(req,res,next) and it will match the path, if there is no related path, it will give 404 not found error.
the calling address:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L47

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made a `/users` route yet.

The `app.use('/users', users)` you have made, take all the routes in the `users` object in relative pathing. so if you create a `/u` in users object, it original url is `http://hostname:port/users/u`. You haven't made a `/users` route which could handle that path.

Create a `router.get('/')` route in your users.js, everything would be fine.